# Relationship Between $\mathbb{E}$(time) and $\mathbb{E}$(Repetition)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Consider aa Stochastic Process with Expected value of time of occurring =T (less than infinity).

Can we deduce that Expected value of number of occurrences until time T is equal to 1??

If not, in general is there some condition or related theorem?

For Example: Consider Geometric Distribution for a "4" occurring in a coin toss.

$\mathbb{E}$(T)=6

$\mathbb{E}$(#4s until t=6)=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#The_elementary_renewal_theorem

The elementary renewal theorem